# JSF Post serialized form to JSF Method without binding value

Tags: javascript, jsf

I've got the following problem: I made a js that generates multiple hidden fields with the same name (in this case 'vak')
I want to be able to post all that data to a JSF method so I can write it to the database.
Thing is, I want to do this without binding the data to variables in the controller

in short, I have a save button that serializes a form(with js generated fields) on click

```
vak=0&vak=1&vak=2&vak=3
```

I want this to end up as an array(list) in the JSF controllers method "handleSave()"

EDIT: this can be closed. I ended up doing it the proper way by handling each change to the calendar as an ajax request and the js just be in charge of the rendering

Comment: You're using JSF in a vary strange way. Use JSF as it is designed with server side components or use some kind of REST API to call a method from JS. It seems that you've misunderstood the idea of JSF. Just tell what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Im making a calendar that has clientside checks for overlapping subjects. when the checks pass it will fill in hidden input and render the calendar accordingly. thats why Im not doing this the way it should be done in JSF. I just need a way to post the data to a method in my controller

Comment: You should have created a JSF component around it. Right now you're totally ignoring JSF's ideology and lifecycle altogether. If you stick in this direction, you'd in first place better have chosen a request/action based MVC framework like SpringMVC or so.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all parameter values by [`ExternalContext#getRequestParameterValuesMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestParameterValuesMap%28%29).

```
String[] vak = externalContext.getRequestParameterValuesMap().get("vak");
```

You'll only need to write some boilerplate code yourself inside the action method in order to convert, validate and update the values (which is what JSF would basically already be Do for you when used the right way).

Comment: this would explain how to get the data but how do I go inside the action method using js?

Comment: Just let JS submit a JSF form by programmatically clicking the (hidden) JSF command link/button.